# VB.Net dispatch function with inherited interfaces

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface, dispatch

I would like to know if there is a way to create a kind of dispatch function using inherited interfaces. 
Let me explain :
Let's say we have a class that do some work and waits for a parameter typed as a base interface (let's says IBaseInterface).
Inside this class, we need to separate the work by the type of the interface.
I would have done this this way :

```
Public Function DoWork(argument As IBaseInterface) As String
    Return Consume(argument)
End Function

Private Function Consume(int As IBaseInterface) As String
    Return "work for Base Interface Object"
End Function

Private Function Consume(int As IInheritedInterface) As String
    Return "work for inherited Interface Object"
End Function
```

When I call dowork with an object that implements IBaseInterface, it should go to the consume with the IBaseInterface parameter (it works like that at this time)
When I call dowork with an object that implements IInheritedInterface, it should call Consume function with the IInheritedInterface (which doesn't work, it always call the function with IBaseInterface argument)

Is there a way to do this kind of stuff without testing if type of object is IBaseInterface or IInheritedInterface (because I could do this with a select case but it's not really a good way of coding I think).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Consume(int As IBaseInterface)` is always called as `DoWork(argument As IBaseInterface)` parameter is always of type IBaseInterface due to automatic casting, so the overload resolution is matching the closest.  If you change your parameter to be an object it should match.  Like this:

```
Public Function DoWork(argument As Object) As String
    Return Consume(argument)
End Function
```